# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED encountered in Dreamweaver preview

Tags: php, localhost, dreamweaver

I am trying to get Dreamweaver preview to work for php applications in Windows 10. it has been a pain so far.

I have the server info of:

[image: Server Info]

and yet I get the this error in DW preview:

[image]

I have xampp running and Apache and Mysql are both started and running with no problems, the file paths are correct, but I am not sure how to fix this myself. google searching didn't give me much either.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the port for HTTP traffic in the Web URL: http://localhost:8080

Comment: I tried that, I think 8080 is used by xampp in the tomcat http port field though, would that effect anything?

Comment: The HTTP port will be set in apache 'httpd.conf'. You'll want to set the listen value to either 80 or 8080 and update the setting in dreamweaver accordingly. Also try to access the page using your web browser, if you are getting the same error there is something else wrong with your HTTP server configs.

Comment: I went into the httpd.conf. It was listening on 81 so i changed it to 80. I tried it in Dreamweaver on both http://localhost:80/ and http://localhost:8080/ and http://localhost/. all gave the same error. I also did a preview in Google Chrome and IE just now. I get the same error there as well. What would be the best route to take in problem solving this? I don't have much experience in this side of web design. :/

Comment: When you changed apache's conf file, be sure to restart or reload the service

Comment: I had restarted thanks for the reminder though! Sometimes I forget that, hehe. I tried going into my localhost just in a normal browser and am running into the same problem...not sure what to change there